# How change some section in AppComponent template when other component is lazy loaded

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have the following template in the `AppComponent`

```
<admin-main-navbar></admin-main-navbar>

<admin-secondary-navbar></admin-secondary-navbar>

<admin-page-header></admin-page-header>

<div class="page-container">
  <div class="page-content">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

the `admin-page-header` is a component with the following template:

```
<div class="page-header">
    <div class="page-title">
      <h4>
        <i class="icon-home position-left"></i>
        Dashboard
      </h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Currently the header part always say **Dashboard**. All sections are lazy loaded inside `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`. I need when go to a section like `/product/list` change the header component title to something like "Products" and change the icon too.

I tried using transclusion but does not works because the new title is defined in a component loaded in `router-outlet`

Comment: I am not sure if my answer to this question can give you some thought, please take a look. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43826897/elegant-way-to-access-the-caption-associated-with-a-router-link-in-angular/43827914#43827914

Comment: Thanks!!, using a service in the core for this works fine!!